# getting "FacebookAuthorizationException: User logged in as different Facebook user" exception - while updating to get new Permission

Tags: facebook, facebook-android-sdk, android-facebook

I am getting FacebookAuthorizationException: User logged in as different Facebook user , while trying to update permission to  publish ,My code looks like below

```
onCreate(...) {
  connectFacebookAccount();
}//oncreate

private void connectFacebookAccount() {
    settings = getSharedPreferences("PREF_NAME",MODE_PRIVATE);
    String FbExperi = settings.getString("FB_AccessExpires, null);
    String accesstoken = settings.getString(FB_AccessToken, null);

    if (accesstoken != null) {
        // open a session from the access token info
        // saved in the app's shared preferences

        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = (Date) new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy",
                    Locale.ENGLISH).parse(FbExperi);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken
                .createFromExistingAccessToken(accesstoken, date, null,
                        null, null);
        Session.openActiveSessionWithAccessToken(NewTest.this, accessToken,
                new Session.StatusCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                            Exception exception) {
                        if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
                            Session.setActiveSession(session);
                            getPublishPremission();
                        }
                    }
                });

    }
}


  private void getPublishPremission(){
    if (Session.getActiveSession().getPermissions() == null
            || !Session.getActiveSession().getPermissions()
                .containsAll(PERMISSIONS)) {
           Session.getActiveSession().requestNewPublishPermissions(
                new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(
                        NewTest.this, PERMISSIONS));

        }else{
          publishFeedDialog()
        }

 private void publishFeedDialog() {
   //open WebDialog to publish feed
 }
```

The execution flow revolves around requestNewPublishPermissions and StatusCallback hence the permission is not set .I request your help to point out where i went wrong.I have an logged in using different facebook Id in my facebook app.In my app i am trying to log-in using different facebook Id  from the access token info  saved in the app's shared preferences.

Comment: Session.getActiveSession().requestNewPublishPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(NewTest.this,PERMISSIONS).setCallback(statusCallback).setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO)); Replacing the above code tigers facebook login dialog ,entering the stored access tokens corresponding facebook Id works fine ,but why does the login dialog should appear when i have already created session using accesstoken

Comment: i am pretty surprised to see that know one came forward to point out the wrong in the code ,Is there is any fault in formatting the code or else cannot understand the code ,please comment.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Have you got your problem solved? Please let me know how you did it?

Comment: Same problem here a year after with the last FB SDK, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

[see](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/333926600053215) this link

There is a bug in facbook sdk,when there is no facebbok app installed on device.When user ask for additional permission,it takes user to the login dialog again.

Comment: Agreed Chirag ,but in my case i have facebook app installed ,but i could not get the desired permission for the session created using access token.Do u mean that is the bug in facebook.This is a problem only when the session is created using accesstoken.

Comment: if you login with FB,while you are logged in your native FB app(Is it?),it will not ask for the login credential again.

Comment: the problem is that i couldn't get publish permission with session created using accesstoken with the above code.

Comment: https://github.com/m3n0R/EasyFacebookConnect
i,m using this library for facebook integration.Its so easy and smooth.Try this may be your problem will be solved.

Comment: I am getting this error even with the Facebook App installed on my device. It's not an option at this point for me to use a different library. Has anyone made any further progress figuring this out?